# Convert make rule to ansible

Tags: ansible

I have the following in a makefile:

```
some_file: some_script
    bash some_script > $@
```

and would like to replicate this in an ansible playbook task, where running the task creates the file anew but only if the generating script file has changed, otherwise it's a no-op. Is there any way to accomplish this using the stock ansible modules?

Comment: Ansible does not store state of what was run in past, but executes "stuff" (sometimes in isolation) and compares the result. Then marks the state as either `changed` or `ok`. But no module has the knowledge of what to compare in a result of a random makefile.

Comment: @techraf I'm trying to replicate the behavior of make in this respect, not run a makefile. Make IIRC looks at the last modified metadata of the generated file and the dependency file and if the latter is more recent will run the rule. Which is why you can force it to run by e.g. `touch`ing the file.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do. Ansible does not store... oh, I already wrote that my first comment.

Comment: @techraf *make doesn't store it either*. As I said in *my* comment, it queries the filesystem. If ansible can't do that, the whatever, tell me it can't e.g. check file metadata. If it can tell me how, but don't make assumptions that run *counter to what I said*. Unless you can prove me wrong. In which case show *how I am wrong*.

Comment: I don't make any assumptions. I told you how Ansible modules work, read my first comment. I did not write about `make`, because you were asking about Ansible, so I explained what Ansible does and does not. You can either accept my comment and implement the logic you want yourself, or stay unhappy that you did not get teh codez on SO in 70 minutes and counting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to execute that in two phases: gather info, then conditionally execute

```
  vars:
    files:
    - some_file
    - some_script
  tasks:
  - stat: path={{ item }}
    register: stats
    with_items: '{{ files }}'
  - debug:
      msg: '{{ stats.results[0].stat.path }} is newer than {{ stats.results[1].stat.path }}'
    when: '{{ stats.results[0].stat.mtime > stats.results[1].stat.mtime }}'
```